# How to get content of span tag in div child?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```html
<div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="real-time-data dark">

  <div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="">
    <span _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__bolder label-range-fall"> 0.00286414 </span>
    <span _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__fs-12 price-cny"> 0.0029 </span>
  </div>
    
  <div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__bolder label-range-fall">-4.95%</div>
    
</div>
```

How to export innerHTML of class **__bolder label-range-fall** of parent class **real-time-data dark** to console.log?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I want get real time price here: https://www.bithumb.pro/en-us/exchange/professional?q=ASK-USDT

Answer (score 2):

You can use querySelector() function.

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".real-time-data span.label-range-fall");
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="real-time-data dark">

  <div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="">
    <span _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__bolder label-range-fall"> 0.00286414 </span>
    <span _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__fs-12 price-cny"> 0.0029 </span>
  </div>
    
  <div _ngcontent-cbl-c27="" class="__bolder label-range-fall">-4.95%</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, i want get real time price here: https://www.bithumb.pro/en-us/exchange/professional?q=ASK-USDT

I use your solution but console.log = undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.querySelector(".real-time-data>.label-range-fall");
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```